# react how to put a <hr /> between 2 .map?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I'm new to react and not very confortable doing a .map in another .map.

I've done it now, the result is exaclty what I wanted except for one thing.
I'd like to separe the results between the 2 .maps with a  `<hr />` but I don't know where to put it.
I tried different places like after the curly bracket from the first .map but it never worked.
Can someone help me please ?

My code :

```
   {data.map((responses) => {
        return responses.answers.map((element) => {
          return (
            <article>
              <div className="question">
                <div
                  className="square"
                >
                  <span>{element.type === "texte" ? "1" : "2"}</span>
                  <img src={Minus} alt="" />
                  <img
                    src={element.type === "texte" ? FileWhite : StarWhite}
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div>{element.question}</div>
              </div>
              {element.type === "texte" ? (
                <div className="answerText">{element.answer}</div>
              ) : (
                <div className="answerNote">
                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note1" name="note" value="1" />
                    <label htmlFor="note1">1</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note2" name="note" value="2" />
                    <label htmlFor="note2">2</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note3" name="note" value="3" />
                    <label htmlFor="note3">3</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note4" name="note" value="4" />
                    <label htmlFor="note4">4</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="square">
                    <input type="radio" id="note5" name="note" value="5" />
                    <label htmlFor="note5">5</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </article>
          );
        });
      })}
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<article class="article">` add margin to article class.

Comment: I tried to add a bottom-border to article but it does not work. The border appears after each elements of the second .map and I only want a border at the elements from the first .map.

Comment: wrap whole first map in div and give border to that div. `<div class"border">{data.map((responses) => {..}` </div>

Comment: Nice !!! I already had it wrap but didn't think of giving it a bottom border.
Thank you !

Comment: Well, I tried your tip but it does not put the hr between the first and second .map it puts it after at the end. So how can I put a <hr> between each element of the FIRST .map ?

Comment: I added a .concate() after the second .map. Finally this method works.